# Understanding design pattern in java

Tags: java

I read in somewhere that developer should always be developing interfaces  and then implement that interface. I am just trying to learn these builder patterns,I guess.. but here is my use case...

I have a central class... say `ProcessFile`

Now, I am writing two formats it can process, one csv another json.

How do I design these classes.

I am guessing it would be something liek this:

```
 public interface CustomFormat{
  //couple of signatures
}
public class csv implements CustomFormat{

}

public class json implements CustomFormat{
}
public class ProcessFiles{
//somehow uses that CustomFormat interface??
}
```

Whats the best way to implement this?

Comment: google for "strategy pattern" and you may find some useful examples.

Comment: look good, but if the application structure is constant(no dynamic), I really suggest you do not follow any specific pattern.

Answer (score 1):

To build on javaPlease42's answer. I would rename ProcessFiles to FileProcessor or something along those lines. A good rule of thumb is to name classes using nouns and methods using verbs to describe what the noun can do. Below is an example of what it could look like.

```
public class FileProcessor {

    public void process(CustomFormat file) {
        // pass in the interface, that way you can use any implementing class 
        // like csv or json
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Whats the best way to implement this?*

I would not use the word Custom in the interface name. Maybe 
FileFormat.java

```
public interface FileFormat {

    public void setFormat(int quantity);
}
```

**CSV.java**

```
public class CSV implements FileFormat{

    @Override
    public void setFormat(int quantity) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

**JSON.java**

```
public class JSON implements FileFormat{

    @Override
    public void setFormat(int quantity) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```